# Failed docker deployment: Cannot find module '/app/heroku'

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, heroku

I have a Node app in Docker I'm trying to deploy to Heroku with this deploy github action: https://github.com/AkhileshNS/heroku-deploy/tree/master

My app is already created in Heroku, and its using the default node buildpack. By all accounts, the deployment appears to succeed on the GHA side.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20 AS base 
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["node", "./src/index.ts"]
```

Here are my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "goal-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Service that powers the Goal API",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/onarollonaroll/goal-service.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.x",
    "npm": "10.x"
  },
  "author": "Onaroll",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn ./src/index.ts",
    "test": "jest",
    "format": "npx prettier --write .",
    "start": "node ./src/index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^10.0.3",
    "@parcel/watcher": "^2.4.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "graphql-yoga": "^5.2.0",
    "heroku": "^8.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.0.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "jest": "^29.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "pretty-quick": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "test"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my folder structure (only showing relevant files):

```
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my `index.ts` (if this needed):

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { gql } from 'graphql-tag'
import { createYoga } from 'graphql-yoga'
import { createServer } from 'http'
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema'
import { resolvers } from './resolvers'

const typeDefs = gql(
  readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './schema.graphql'), {
    encoding: 'utf-8',
  })
)

function startYogaServer() {
  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers })
  const yoga = createYoga({ schema })
  const server = createServer(yoga)
  server.listen(4000, () => {
    console.info('Server is running on http://localhost:4000/graphql')
  })
}

startYogaServer()
```

If I try to open the app via Heroku, I get a standard "Application Error" that tells me to check the logs.

In the logs I see this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/heroku'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

I didn't think my app needed to install Heroku, but I tried installing it anyways (`npm install heroku`) and still get the same error.

I saw a suggestion elsewhere recommending I set `NODE_MODULES_CACHE` to false in Heroku, which I've also done, to no avail.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: I now think this above error may be an error caused by running `heroku logs --tail` via the heroku CLI on the heroku website, because maybe my container doesn't have Heroku installed?

When I click "View logs" in the dropdown on the service's heroku page, I see these logs:

```
2024-03-26T13:48:40.543188+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-03-26T13:48:40.543188+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v20.11.1
2024-03-26T13:48:40.606107+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-03-26T13:48:40.627333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2024-03-26T13:48:42.941754+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=goal-service-staging-3c32681ee39d.herokuapp.com request_id=d654a8fe-0ceb-46c5-b2ea-2ae63a7fe2d5 fwd="72.74.249.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-03-26T13:48:43.066833+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=goal-service-staging-3c32681ee39d.herokuapp.com request_id=68a2d6fa-e9b3-422e-a80b-bab6cbad21e8 fwd="72.74.249.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-03-26T13:49:01.893680+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `heroku logs --tail` by user ryanmk@onaroll.co
2024-03-26T13:49:18.874678+00:00 heroku[run.5163]: State changed from starting to up
2024-03-26T13:49:22.565432+00:00 heroku[run.5163]: Process exited with status 1
2024-03-26T13:49:22.590829+00:00 heroku[run.5163]: State changed from up to complete
```

Which I'm not sure provide any additional information or not. I cannot see what is causing the 503.

Comment: Not an expert in this domain, but that error message suggests (to me!) that it's looking for a local file rather than the package you would get via `npm install heroku`). Could you please share a minimal version of your `src/index.ts` which replicates the problem? Would also be helpful to see your complete `package.json`.

Comment: @datawookie The index.ts is super simple currently - just spinning up a yoga server for GQL. It is only serving static data currently, via one query. This is simply a POC with very little complications. 

I will add that and the full package.json to the original post.

Comment: This won't even build locally for me. I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error relating to the first line of code (`import { readFileSync } from 'fs'`).

It's hard to debug a runtime error if you can't get the image to build. I'm happy to figure this out, but presumably you have a full setup which builds, so can you please share that?

Comment: Ah, crap. Yeah, I had the incorrect start command. In my package.json, it should be this: `"start": "ts-node src/index.ts"` and in my Dockerfile this `CMD ["ts-node", "src/index.ts"]`.

Even after making these changes, and the app starts locally, I am seeing the same error in Heroku logs

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. And I see that you have `ts-node` listed in your `package.json`. However, the `ts-node` executable doesn't seem to be installed on your path but rather at `/app/node_modules/.bin/ts-node`. Have you added this directory to your `PATH` somewhere? I would expect to see that in your `Dockerfile` maybe?

Comment: I have some new information to add here. I think that when I run `heroku logs --tail` in the Heroku CLI (via the website), I'm getting the error I posted in my origin message, because the docker container I deployed doesn't understand the `heroku` command?

Separately, if I view logs directly via the dropdown on the service page in Heroku, I see different logs, which I've added to my original post. 

Going to look into the ts-node suggestion above now.

Comment: I needed to globally install `ts-node` to get the app to start correctly. I also needed to use `process.env.PORT` in my `index.ts`, instead of a hard-coded value.

Comment: Glad I could help you reach that conclusion. Would have been really helpful to have included all of this information in the original question. 

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me ended up being adjusting my `Dockerfile` to correctly start the app.

As such, here is my new `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:20 AS base 
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install && npm install ts-node -g
COPY . .
CMD ["ts-node", "src/index.ts"]
```

I needed to use `ts-node` to run the app, and it needed to be installed globally to work here.

Additionally, I needed to use `process.env.PORT` in my `index.ts` rather than a hard-coded value.